# Scheduling shortest job first in c

Tags: c, scheduling

So I am working on scheduling, including FCFS and Shortest Job First. I am really struggling with my Shortest Job First, I can't see my logic error. I have it print out, and some of the numbers are correct, but not all of them. The test file that I use has the following text:

```
1   0   6
2   3   2
3   5   1
4   9   7
5   10  5
6   12  3
7   14  4
8   16  5
9   17  7
10  19  2
```

I use the < command to just redirect the input to come from the file when testing, so something of the sort of `./a.out < test.txt`.

Any help, pointers or code, would be much appreciated!

*edit* I think that my problem is logic based in the sfj function. For the input, the first column is the process id, the second is the time of arrival and the third is the burst time or how long the process needs with the cpu.

The output I get is:

```
Shortest Job First
PID     WAIT    TURNAROUND
1       0       6
2       15      17
3       3       4
4       0       7
5       6       11
6       9       12
7       10      14
8       12      17
9       16      23
10      21      23
Average Wait: 9 Average Turnaround 13
```

When I actually expect:

```
Shortest Job First

Pid     Wait    Turnaround
1       0       6
2       4       6
3       1       2
4       0       7
5       15      20
6       4       7
7       7       11
8       14      19
9       18      25
10      0       2
Average wait: 6.3 Average turnaround: 10.5
```

---

```
//  File.c
//  Project6
//
//  Created by Chris on 6/19/14.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#define LINELEN 512
#define MAX_PROCESS 100

typedef struct process
{
    int ID;
    int arrival_time;
    int time_to_completion;
    int wait_time;
    int turn_around;
    int active;

}process;
void fcfs(struct process[MAX_PROCESS], int);
void sjf (struct process[MAX_PROCESS], int);
void srtn(struct process[MAX_PROCESS], int);
void rr (struct process[MAX_PROCESS], int);
void rrc(struct process[MAX_PROCESS], int);
void print_info(struct process[MAX_PROCESS], int);
void sort_by_time(struct process array[MAX_PROCESS], int num_valid_pid);

int main(int ac,char *av[])
{
    int counter=0;
    int p1=0, p2=0, p3=0;
    process array[MAX_PROCESS];
    while ( scanf("%d %d %d", &p1, &p2, &p3) != EOF ){//Get all the info available and put it in array of structs
        array[counter].ID = p1;
        array[counter].arrival_time = p2;
        array[counter].time_to_completion = p3;
        counter++;
    }
    fcfs(array, counter);
    sjf (array, counter);
    /*srtn(array, counter);
    rr (array, counter);
    rrc(array, counter);*/
    return 0;
}
void fcfs(struct process array[MAX_PROCESS], int num_pid){
    //for loop num_pid
    int i;
    int current_time = 0;
    for(i=0; i<num_pid; i++){
    //if arrival is < current time, wait time = current time - arrival
        if(array[i].arrival_time < current_time)
            array[i].wait_time = current_time - array[i].arrival_time;
    //if arrival is >= current time, wait time = 0;
        else if(array[i].arrival_time >= current_time)
            array[i].wait_time = 0;
    //current time = current time + wait time + time to completion
        current_time= current_time + array[i].time_to_completion;
    //turnaround time = wait time + time to completion
        array[i].turn_around = array[i].wait_time + array[i].time_to_completion;
    }
    printf("First Come First Serve\n");
    print_info(array, num_pid);
}
void sjf (struct process array[MAX_PROCESS], int num_pid){
    printf("Shortest Job First\n");//for the output so we know what algorithm
    //create an array of pids that are valid to search.
    int num_valid_processes = 0, current_time=0, i,j, next_process, counter = 0;//declarations
    process to_sort[MAX_PROCESS];

    //we want to do this next loop for as many processes as we have, or num_pid
    for(j=0; j<num_pid; j++){
        //adds all the available processes to the to sort array to be sorted
        //available means that it has arrived, which means it is <= current_time
        //after it gets all the processes, it breaks out of the for loop
        for(i=counter; i<num_pid; i++){
            if(array[i].arrival_time<=current_time){
                to_sort[i]=array[i];
                num_valid_processes++;
                counter++;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        //sort the to_sort array by the time_to_completion
        sort_by_time(to_sort,num_valid_processes);

        //set the wait time and turnaround time for the next process
        next_process = to_sort[0].ID;
        array[next_process].wait_time = current_time-array[next_process].arrival_time;
        array[next_process].turn_around = array[next_process].wait_time + array[next_process].time_to_completion;
        //change the current_time and continue
        //current time = current time + wait time + time to completion
        current_time= current_time + array[next_process].time_to_completion;

        //delete the process we just worked on so we don't get duplicates.
        num_valid_processes--;
        for(i=0;i<num_valid_processes;i++){
            to_sort[i]=to_sort[i+1];
        }
    }
    //loop back up to get available processes
    //now all the info in out first array is filled out, print it out.
    print_info(array, num_pid);
}

void print_info(struct process array[MAX_PROCESS], int num_pid){
    int i;
    int tot_wait=0, tot_turn = 0;
    printf("\x1b[04mPID\tWAIT\tTURNAROUND\n\x1b[24m");
    for(i=0; i<num_pid; i++){
        printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n", array[i].ID, array[i].wait_time, array[i].turn_around);
        tot_wait=tot_wait+array[i].wait_time;
        tot_turn = tot_turn +array[i].turn_around;
    }
    printf("Average Wait: %d Average Turnaround %d\n", tot_wait/num_pid, tot_turn/num_pid);
}

void sort_by_time(struct process array[MAX_PROCESS], int num_valid_pid)
{
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < num_valid_pid; i++)
    {
        int min = i;
        for (j = i+1; j < num_valid_pid; j++)
            if (array[j].time_to_completion < array[min].time_to_completion)
                min = j;
        process temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[min];
        array[min] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @user3746000. FYI, it's customary around here to explain a bit about where you have isolated the problems to rather than just "look at my whole program and tell me why it won't work".

Comment: What do the three columns represent? The first is presumably the job number, but what are the other two?  What output do you get? What output do you expect?

Comment: Edited the post to give a bit more information

Comment: I guess my problem could also be in the sort_by_time function at the bottom.

Comment: Have you considered a [min-heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Heap_implementation) for this? Seriously, it appears you're trying to implement a [*priority queue*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue), and

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm not sure how to do the heap in C. This was just the way that clicked for me, but if you give some pointers on what I should do with the heap I will gladly give it a try.

Comment: @user3746000 the link provided in the comment essentially talks about how to build a [heap structure in an array backdrop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Heap_implementation). The algorithm is fairly simple, with two primary operations: pushing new elements in (a *heap-up*), and resifting from the head down after removing an element (a *heap-down*). There should be *tons* of examples on the web for such implementations, as it is very common to implement at least once as part of comp-sci curricula.

Comment: So what is the benefit of doing the heap instead of what I have done, using an array of structs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being in the sjf function, the for loop for assignment was incorrect, should have been

```
for(i=counter; i<num_pid; i++){
        if(array[i].arrival_time<=current_time){
            to_sort[num_valid_process]=array[i];
            num_valid_processes++;
            counter++;
        }
...
```